«А именно» как вводное
Такой текст:
Он решил сделать мне подарок, после чего я не мог больше быть не на его стороне. А именно, котенка.
После "а именно" — нужен ли знак препинания, и если да, то какой?


Другой вариант оформления:

Он решил сделать мне подарок, после чего я не мог больше быть не на его стороне. А именно — котенка.
Пояснение
Интонационное тире поставлено в неполном предложении: А именно — котенка. Пропущено сказуемое "подарил".

Возможно использование сказуемого в самом  тексте, такая стилистика выглядит даже  корректнее:

Он решил сделать мне подарок, после чего я не мог больше быть не на его стороне. А именно — подарил котенка.
Должно быть соответствие: сделал подарок — подарил котенка. А интонационное тире в любом случае сохраняется.

Правильно:
Он решил сделать мне подарок, после чего я не мог больше быть не на его стороне. А именно котенка.
Пояснение

А ИМЕННО, союз
А. Вводит в предложение пояснительные члены – слова или 
словосочетания, которые конкретизируют то, о чём 
говорится до союза. Пояснительные члены предложения, 
присоединяемые союзом «а именно», обособляются.
Последний был членом Кабинета министров, а именно 
товарищем министра информации. В. Аксенов, Остров Крым.


В приведенном предложении использована парцелляция  пояснительного члена.
Парцелляция в русском языке — это такое синтаксическое 
построение текста, в котором используется намеренное 
членение связной мысли на составляющие её части. В 
переводе с французского языка слово parcella буквально 
значит «частица».



